# Editable UITextView with multiple columns

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit

I need to develop a text editor (UITextView) that will have multiple columns. I'm currently trying to accomplish this using Text Kit. Unfortunately, we can only use one TextContainer in UITextView (textContainer property).

I've seen a lot of implementation rendering text UITextView with multiple columns bit our requirement is different since it has to be editable. Multiple UITextViews does not work since we need to properly adjust the text position and cursor to overflow from/to the previous/next column.

Has anyone achieved this already?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Was there ever an update to this? It looks like out of the box this is still the case